# pip cannot install Image or Pillow library on Windows 7

Tags: python-3.4, python-imaging-library

I downloaded Pillow binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil 
 for my version of Python (3.4.2) and Windows (32 bit).

`pip install Pillow-3.4.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` fails with the error message below:

`Pillow-3.4.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

The debug log is given below:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip run on 03/26/17 16:04:25
Pillow-3.4.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 167, in from_line
    raise UnsupportedWheel("%s is not a supported wheel on this platform." % wheel.filename)
pip.exceptions.UnsupportedWheel: Pillow-3.4.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I have found and fixed the problems. There were two. Writing them here hoping it would help someone.

1. First problem was: I have python version `3.4.2`, but was trying to install `Pillow-3.4.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl`, which after some searches I realized was meant for Python 3.6.x (that is the cp36 part). This time I downloaded `pillow-4.0.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl`.
2. The second and the main problem was: my pip was outdated. After doing a `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then rerunning the original installation command `pip install pillow-4.0.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl`, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip3 install pillow[........]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben Richter. I got the same error message with pip3.